# Single mesh vs separate objects parented together

Tags: modeling

If you're modeling something, when would you choose to try to make it one mesh vs using different objects and parenting them etc?

For example, in the very popular anvil tutorial by Blender Guru, he does everything in one mesh through manipulating it (and goes through a painstaking process to ensure that there is a single clean mesh).

However, in another tutorial I watched on CGCookie where a lamp is made, all the parts of the lamp are separate objects.

I've seen this question but it doesn't really discuss the advantages or disadvantages: [Single continuous mesh vs disconnected parts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/single-continuous-mesh-vs-disconnected-parts)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116017

Comment: In many ways it is up to you how you want to work, and how you orgainze your elements. There isn't a single way to create, whatever works for you should be OK. Working on separate pieces can be a bit more complex, as you need to plan carefully how you are going to fit the pieces together at the end if you are looking for deformations. For mechanical objects or some rigs might be easier to have different elements, for organic shapes it is not as straight forward. What kind of objects are we talking about?